Package fontspec not working when using Overleaf via Sciebo
My university decided to provide us with student accounts for Overleaf, via Sciebo. It seems though, that when using Overleaf via Sciebo, it breaks something. While I was formerly able to simply load the Charis SIL font with fontspec, it now 'cannot find' said font. Does anybody know why that is or what I can do to fix it?
Here my code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{BabelStone Han}
\setCJKmonofont{BabelStone Han}
\setCJKsansfont{BabelStone Han}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\par
メロスは激怒した。必ず、かの邪智暴虐の王を除かなければならぬと決意した。メロスには政治がわからぬ。メロスは、村の牧人である。笛を吹き、羊と遊んで暮して来た。けれども邪悪に対しては、人一倍に敏感であった。きょう未明メロスは村を出発し、野を越え山越え、十里はなれた此のシラクスの市にやって来た。\par
Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı 1500'lerden beri endüstri standardı sahte metinler olarak kullanılmıştır.\par
Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях.\par
\end{document}

On my normal Overleaf account this works just fine. Output:

Beautiful. Exactly what I wanted, and no error messages (ignoring the "Overfull \hbox" for now).
Using my Sciebo account though, I get an error message. I am still using XeLaTeX and copied all the other settings from my original account. Same code, same settings (as far as I can tell), Output:

Package fontspec Error: The font "Charis SIL" cannot be found.
Font TU/CharisSIL(0)/m/n/10="Charis SIL" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "BabelStone Han" cannot be found.
Font TU/BabelStoneHan(0)/m/n/10="BabelStone Han/OT" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

Ugly. Repugnant. Not what I wanted.
A fix I did find was to manually add the fonts I wanted, by uploading the .ttfs to the Overleaf project. New code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}[
    Path=./CharisSIL/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic
    ]

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{BabelStoneHan}[
    Path=./BabelStoneHan/,
    Extension = .ttf
    ]
\setCJKmonofont{BabelStoneHan}[
    Path=./BabelStoneHan/,
    Extension = .ttf
    ]
\setCJKsansfont{BabelStoneHan}[
    Path=./BabelStoneHan/,
    Extension = .ttf
    ]

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\par
メロスは激怒した。必ず、かの邪智暴虐の王を除かなければならぬと決意した。メロスには政治がわからぬ。メロスは、村の牧人である。笛を吹き、羊と遊んで暮して来た。けれども邪悪に対しては、人一倍に敏感であった。きょう未明メロスは村を出発し、野を越え山越え、十里はなれた此のシラクスの市にやって来た。\par
Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı 1500'lerden beri endüstri standardı sahte metinler olarak kullanılmıştır.\par
Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях.\par
\end{document}

(Output same as working picture above)
Now, this does work, but one of the main reasons I like using Overleaf is that I don't have to constantly download (and upload) stuff. I also think that this behaviour is unexpected enough to warrant the question why it happens.
I realise this problem is probably difficult to recreate for most users here, as not all will have access to Sciebo. Thanks anyway.

check the left sidebar of each project that they are using the same version of texlive. If you have a long lived project and overleaf release a new version with a new texlive they do not automatically change existing projects.

Have you asked the Overleaf Helpdesk for advice?

The project cache on Overleaf is stored per user, not per project (at least that used to be the case). It might be that you got something corrupted in one account but not the other. Try clearing the cache (used to be possible via the small menu where you can also get the log).

I recommend contacting Sciebo for support rather than Overleaf as Sciebo are using their own version. This is the open-source version from GitHub. There are some differences e.g. lack of integration with GitHub and Zotero. If it works in your Overleaf account but still doesn't work in Sciebo and you've tried @Skillmon's advice, Sciebo's support are the people to ask. [Note that this advice is based on a Google Translate rendition of the German into Welsh. Given it translated 'Overleaf' to my utter bewilderment, though not consistently, rely on this advice at your peril.]

Thanks for all the advice!
One difference between OG Overleaf and Sciebo's version of Overleaf is seemingly that you cannot change the texlive version. So even if that is the problem, I guess I cannot fix that myself.
I have also cleared the cache and recompiled from scratch, but the problem persisted. I would like to try recreating the problem with another account, too, but we sadly only get one.
I have contacted the Sciebo help desk and received a message that they are 'on it', so this is currently the best lead. If nothing comes from it, I will also contact Overleaf.

Could you change your title to include 'Sciebo' so this is easier for other users to find?

@cfr Good idea. Done.

@LHDStack Thanks!

Though I have not achieved or received a good solution to the above stated problem, I have received answers both from the Sciebo support and Overleaf Helpdesk.
On the one hand, the Sciebo support team answered: "We use the Open Source version of Overleaf as it is found of GitHub. That means that we do not have influence on the usable features."
On the other hand, the Overleaf Helpdesk responded to my inquiry as follows:

The reason for this is that the Community Edition uses a basic scheme version of TeXLive for compiles. This basic version is lightweight and only contains a very limited subset of LaTeX packages, which can result in missing package/font errors.
I see from your forum post that you managed to work around the problem by uploading the missing fonts to your project. Unfortunately, until the Scibo team installs the missing packages/fonts, this is the only way to handle this.
For further help in this regard, I'd recommend reaching out to the Scibo team. The general help pages for Overleaf Community Edition and Server Pro can be found here: https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/wiki. The support team at Scibo can find information about upgrading TexLive/package management here. If the Scibo team runs into any technical issues after reviewing the help, they can always open a ticket for community-based support on GitHub.

So for the moment, there is seemingly no solution for the simple user to resolve the issue other than to work around it as I described in the question. Furthermore, judging from Overleaf's response, the problem should extend to other packages as well. At the very least, if we are to believe the Overleaf Helpdesk, the problem indeed lies with Sciebo, not Overleaf or fontspec. I will continue to haunt the Sciebo support team to fix the issue to my best capabilities.

Thanks for reporting back! I somewhat suspect Sciebo do not know a great deal about TeX. There is not much you can do about that besides haunt them :).
